# Necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of a bitangent

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, curves, algebraic-curves

For a 2D curve defined over a limited range, is the existence of a region over which the sign of the curvature is the opposite from the rest of the range both necessary and sufficient to prove the existence of a bitangent (a line tangent to the curve at two distinct points)? If so, could someone direct me to a method of proof (or an existing proof) that someone who is well-versed in math but deficient in elementary analysis could understand?

For context, I have a computation which is implicitly defined and so is solved iteratively; it *resembles* a quartic curve, and so *can* possess a bitangent.  For convenience, let's call the computation *f*(*x*); the computation also depends on a parameter (which we can call *s*), but for a given dataset, the parameter is fixed.  For some values of *s*, *f*(*x*) has a bitangent, while for others is does not.  I need to find the threshold of *s* at which the bitangent disappears.  My concept was to write code which scanned *f*(*x*) over all available *x*-values, use this scan to estimate the second derivative, and then scan that code over *s* values looking for the threshold at which the sign changes stop occurring.  I could then, if desired, make the scan increment of *x* or *s* finer to refine the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a subtle point. What's going on is that the *dual curve* (the curve of tangent lines in the space of lines in the plane) has a double point precisely when the original curve has a bitangent.

The space of lines in the plane is a two-dimensional space (basically the projective plane missing a point). Consider the tangent line to $y=f(x)$ at $x=a$: It's given by the equation $y=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a) = f'(a)x + (f(a)-af'(a))$. So let your computer  plot the points
$$\big(f'(a),f(a)-af'(a)\big)$$
as $a$ varies. Look for where double points in this curve appear and disappear.

Comment: I believe I understand your instructions, if not the underlying mathematics.  However (and I do realize this is a bit off-topic), since I am going to have to plot these points for various values of *s* and look for the first such value (as *s* rises, in my case) where the plot no longer crosses itself, and since I must do so numerically, what would be the best algorithmic way to detect such a crossing (and lack thereof) – I can't rely upon my human ability to look at a plot and see it, I have to code the computer to see it.

Comment: Also, although I understand you are giving me the necessary and sufficient condition, is there a way to prove or disprove that, in my case or in general, these conditions are not equivalent to looking for a region of opposite curvature in the middle of the range?  I hope to eventually be publishing this method (in the field of chemistry, for what it's worth) and it would be a boon to my submission if I could definitively say either that my curvature method is inaccurate or that it does work (at least for this class of problems).

Comment: I don't have a good answer for your first question, as I am not a numerics person. For the second question, your curvature criterion need not work. You can take such a curve (say a very shallow sine wave followed by another, but join the two by a very long almost vertical curve, thereby shifting the expected second points of tangency too far up).

Comment: By the way, other than looking at the picture, you can get a little system of equations: We want $a\ne b$ with $f’(a)=f’(b)$ and $f(a)-af’(a)=f(b)-bf’(b)$ (which is of course what we get when we say the tangent lines at $a$ and $b$ are the same).

Comment: I should make clear that my curve is a *function*, but it probably not *algebraic* (being a complex sum/product of natural logarithms and other bits).  The more I think about it, the more convinced I am that, for a function, the conditions for the existence of a bitangent must be equivalent to a region of opposite curvature over the domain of the function (which is a continuous subset of [0,1] and varies with the parameter *s*).

Comment: The problem I am running into in employing your definition (which, I must say, I knew nothing about but I find the dual curve plots fascinating) is that the step size which will reveal a crossing for curves near the threshold seems to be much less than is ideal for estimating the derivatives; indeed, it seems (computationally) prohibitively small.  I am currently trying to find a value of *s* for which the dual curve has no *visible* self-crossing but for which I can determine the bitangent and which has a region of opposite-sign curvature.

Comment: As I said, your curvature changes sign twice condition is not sufficient. So, from a mathematical perspective, that seems to be a dead end.

Comment: The curvature change conditions do seem to be *necessary*, so what additional conditions are required so that the set of conditions is *sufficient*?  What more does the existence of a node in the dual curve tell me, or is the dual curve not interpretable in terms of properties of the original curve?

Comment: I have been thinking about your example of a shallow sine curve joined to another by a long nearly vertical curve.  If I have understood this description, then the second sine is vertically shifted to a great extent.  If each sine is only one half-wave's worth, then I can see how there might be no bitangent, but if each sine has a full wave, then it would still possess a bitangent – and if it is only a half-wave's worth, the curvature sign changes but doesn't change back.

Answer (score 1):

No. A bitangent to a curve intersects it at $4$ points counting multiplicity, so [Bézout's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem) implies that an algebraic curve admitting a bitangent has degree $\geq 4$. But the curvature of a cubic plane curve can have different signs at different points (consider, e.g., any cubic $y = p(x)$, where $\deg p = 3$).

Comment: In your sentence "a bitangent to a curve..." you should say "a curve defined by a **cartesian** equation..." (even if it is clear that it is this kind of curve which is under consideration by the author of the question). Indeed it is not true for a curve such as a hyperbola defined by an **implicit** equation.

Comment: Can the curvature of a cubic plane curve with finite range and domain change sign *twice*?  This change-and-change-back is what my code is detecting.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the comment. Could you clarify? To me an algebraic curve is defined by one or more Cartesian equations. I haven't seen "implicit" used in contrast to "Cartesian" before.

Comment: @TedLorance Yes, e.g., $y^2 = x^3 + 1$.

Comment: @Travis Willse  I agree that I shouldn't have used "cartesian" which can be applied for both "implicit" and "explicit" forms. Do we agree that an implicit equation, say in two unknowns $x,y$, is an equation which is not given (or cannot be turned) under the form y=f(x) : in this implict case, no notion of  *so-called* "dependent" variable say $y$ isolated "explicitly" on, say, the LHS of the equation, with all occurences of the "independent" variable $x$ on its RHS.

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable to me, but I still don't understand your original comment. Can you give an explicit example for which the claim isn't true?

Comment: @TravisWillse I see now my confusion (perhaps our confusion): my curve is a function with a continuous derivative but may not be algebraic (it *resembles* a quartic polynomial function, but it isn't one and can't be exactly represented by one).  Would this restriction change your response?

Comment: @TedLorance No, it remains a counterexample to the stronger claim, too.

Comment: @Travis Willse I have realized that my counterexample with an hyperbola isn't valid because it is its asymptotes which are bitangent to the curve at points ... at infinity.

Comment: @JeanMarie Actually, as a strict function it would be possible to isolate the dependent variable to one side and the independent to the other; it is just that the function involved is a complex sum and product of logarithms of the independent variable rather than a strictly algebraic function.